# Cannot Resolve 'junit' with Junit 4.12 in my Maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I am having an issue about the junit, the IDE cannot resolve symbol for 'junit' even if I have it installed:
[image]

If I changed junit to version 4.11, this problem will be solved, but every time I run the test, it will give me error and ask me to use junit 4.12 or higher version.

Here is my project dependencies:
[image]

Anyone knows how to solve it? I have finish everything, and just waiting for the test. Thanks in advance!

Run 'mvn clean package', gives compilation error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project cached an older version. 
You don't have to set junit version, the annotation spring-boot-starter-test will take care of it.
Please consider running clean command in terminal at parent root folder:

```
mvn clean
```

And reimport dependencies by clicking Manven Projects on the right and the first button:

[image]

If it does not work, maybe you installed an older version by mistake. You should run:

```
mvn clean package
```

UPDATE:

Your maven repository .m2 folder has multiple versions of junit.
 The simplest way is to delete and build the project again. The .m2 folder will be recreated automatically.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried both ways, none of them work, and run 'mvn clean package' even gives the compilation error,  and I added the screenshot above for your reference.

Comment: Is your test class is located in src/test/java folder? If it is in src/main/java it will not work

Comment: Yes, it is in the src/test/java folder, btw, I used start.spring.io to initiate the project.

Comment: Please try to delete .m2 folder and try again

Comment: great, delete it and run mvn clean package again

Answer (score 1):

Two things you could try:

- Right click on the project, go under *Maven* and click on *Reimport*
- Go to *File* and select *Invalidate Caches / Restart*

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried the two ways, but the problem remains.

Comment: @ZiruLiu Are you able to run the tests from command line (for example via `mvn test`)?

Comment: @ZiruLiu Also, what spring-boot version are you using?

Comment: My spring boot version is 2.0.5

Comment: And ran `mvn test` gives the same compilation error as the screenshot I attached above.

Comment: If you look under ./m2/repository/junit/junit are you able to find the junit4.12 zip there?

Comment: And did you override the default maven central repository in your setting.xml?

Comment: Sorry, where is ./m2 folder, I am not able to find it.

Comment: C://Users/Ziru/.m2. You can see it in the terminal error.

Comment: Is this the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600028/maven-error-in-opening-zip-file-when-running-maven

Comment: See the above link, it seems you experience the same issue.

Comment: And I am not sure how to override the default maven central repository, and where is setting.xml? Do you mean pom.xml?

Comment: No, maven uses a file called setting.xml (located in your .m2 folder) to define, among other things, from where to fetch your dependencies.

Comment: If you did not override it ignore that suggestion, it is not the cause for your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, problem solved after I deleted m2 folder, and run `mvn clean package`.