# Upgrading groovy-all dependency to 2.5

Tags: java, maven, groovy, pom.xml

I'm trying to upgrade [groovy-all](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html) from 2.3.x to 2.5.x, but I noticed that they no longer provide a groovy-all jar and instead provide a [super POM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.5.8/groovy-all-2.5.8.pom) that lists out all the groovy libraries as dependencies.
Previously, this is what I had in my parent pom:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
      </dependency>
..
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

And in my child pom:

```
  <parent> .. </parent>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

This worked fine -- now I'm trying to upgrade to 2.5.x with these changes:
parent pom:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.8</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
..
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

And child pom:

```
<parent> .. </parent>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.8</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

However, now I'm getting this error:

Unable to list entries for jar: /Users//.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.5.8/groovy-all-2.5.8.pom: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]

How can I import the dependencies of this "all" pom using maven? Should I be changing something in the pom.xml files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven : error in opening zip file when running maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600028/maven-error-in-opening-zip-file-when-running-maven)