# Intellij mvn install complains "cannot access <package>" during testComplile after adding cucumber-junit-platform-engine dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

I am planning to use Cucumber Test with Junit 5 in Maven. So I followed [cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine) to install different maven dependency. I added a runner class to execute my cucumber tests

```
package pirate;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("pirate")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pirate")
public class Runner {}
```

I also created a new folder name `pirate` under `resources` folder and move all `.feature` files into that new folder.
But when I execute `mvn clean install`, the command fails at testCompile:
[image]
It seems like the compiler can't read the package name?
Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>onetwothree</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>onetwothree</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
              cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
            </configurationParameters>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My project structure is:

[image]

but if I comment out `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` dependency in `pom.xml`, the error is gone but it won't run the cucumber tests. Did I miss something here?

Not sure if it's related, but one of the error messages is like:

```
[ERROR] error reading /Users/xx/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.9.1/junit-platform-engine-1.9.1.jar; zip file is empty
[ERROR] /Users/xx/Desktop/zz/src/test/java/pirate/Runner.java:[1,1] cannot access pirate
  ZipException opening "junit-platform-engine-1.9.1.jar": zip END header not found
```

Comment: Does the project build outside of IntelliJ IDEA using command line `mvn clean package`? Why do you think it's IntelliJ IDEA issue?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I only built it with Intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maven : error in opening zip file when running maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600028/maven-error-in-opening-zip-file-when-running-maven)

following the procedure fixes the "cannot access " problem.

Comment: Solved it for me, a download got corrupted and the jar file was empty.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried with a different scope than test for the cucumber-junit-platform-engine dependency?

Comment: yes, I used <compile> but the error now occurs at ```compile``` stage -- it's complaining ```cannot access package``` in my production code